# How to use prediction model after onehot encoding?

Tags: python, prediction, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I have created a prediction model for this dataset

```
>>df.head()

    Service    Tasks Difficulty     Hours
0   ABC         24     1           0.833333
1   CDE         77     1           1.750000
2   SDE         90     3           3.166667
3   QWE         47     1           1.083333
4   ASD         26     3           1.000000

>>df.shape
(998,4)

>>X = df.iloc[:,:-1]
>>y = df.iloc[:,-1].values
>>from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer 
>>ct = ColumnTransformer([("cat", OneHotEncoder(),[0])], remainder="passthrough")
>>X = ct.fit_transform(X)  
>>x = X.toarray()
>>x = x[:,1:]

>>x.shape
(998,339)

>>from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
>>rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 1)
>>rf_model.fit(x,y)
```

How can I use this model to predict `Hours` for user input in this format `[["SDE", 90, 3]]`

I tried

```
>>test_input = [["SDE", 90, 3]]
>>test_input = ct.fit_transform(test_input)  
>>test_input = test_input[[:,1:]

>>test_input[0]
array([24, 1], dtype=object)


>>predict_hours = rf_model.predict(test_input)
ValueError
```

Since my dataset has many `categorical` values its not possible enter the encoded value of `"SDE"` as input, I need to convert `"SDE"` to `onehot encoded` format after receiving the input `[["SDE", 90, 3]]`

I don't know how to do it can anyone help?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Since there are many sites that illustrate using one-hot encoding, we expect you to use those well before post here.

Comment: Don't use `fit_transform()` on both your training and prediction samples. `fit()` your transformer(s) to your training data, then `transform()` both your training and test data with the fitted transformer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pipeline` for easily handling preprocess and classification stages

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# I have created a dummy dataset
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

X = df.iloc[:,:-1]
y = df.iloc[:,-1].values

# preprocessor
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([("cat", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'),[0])], remainder="passthrough")

# create a pipeline with preprocessor and classifier
pipeline = Pipeline([('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 1))
                      ])
# split dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5,
                                                    random_state=0)

# train the pipelime
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict
print(pipeline.predict(X_test))
```